# In the 'Wheel of Time' series, what is the game of stones?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, inspiration

In the Wheel of Time, there are numerous mentions of the game of stones. The only characteristics about it I remember are:

- It's played between 2 players on a board.
- It is about placing (not moving) stones on a board.

Given these characteristics, I take it to be the game of GO. Has this been confirmed by any of the authors? Are there any other games it plausibly may be?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like Robert Jordan said that it was made-up game, but that is was meant to resemble GO.

- [How do you play the game of stones from The wheel of time?](https://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_do_you_play_the_game_of_stones_from_The_wheel_of_time) on Answers.com.
- [Wheel of Time - Stones](https://senseis.xmp.net/?WheelOfTimeStones) on Sensei's Library.

Comment: A better citation would probably be the reconstruction of the game from the books on [The Thirteenth Depository](http://13depository.blogspot.com/2009/03/stones.html).

Comment: -1 wiki.answers.com is not a trustworthy source.

Comment: @Bill : You should have put it up as an answer. I was hesistant to accept this one because of the unverifiability.

Comment: @apoorv020: I was going to, but my link isn't a confirmation by one of the authors either.  I've asked a friend to take a look at this, though.  He's a very strong Go player and a huge WoT fan (who has met both RJ and Brandon Sanderson).  If there's an authoritative reference, I'm pretty confident he'll be able to come up with it.

Comment: @Bill, thanks for the better source. I thought the 2nd link was better, but yours offers a MUCH better explanation. I thought that an answer would be better than nothing at all.

Comment: @Teknophilia: I agree, your second link is good.  Coincidentally, the TimK who commented on that page is the friend I was referring to in my second comment above.  :)

Comment: I was hoping for some written documentation, but I kind of expected this.  http://twitter.com/TimKington/status/42304369529462784

Comment: That guy should start sharing some great questions/answers on this site @Bill

Comment: @IvoFlipse: I'll keep working on him.  He's a really good guy to talk to about sci-fi & fantasy books.

Comment: It would help though if you explained to those who aren't familiar with it, what the game actually looks like with some fan-art perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

I think another great resource is Linda's article on 13th depository blog,
 [here](http://13depository.blogspot.com/2009/03/stones.html) .  Like all her articles, this one goes into elaborate details as to the possible origins and real world references of the game, rules of the game, and how it can be replicated and played in the real world if wanted. Also mentions of different character interactions in relation to the game are mentioned.

Comment: When your answer is essentially a link, please provide a short summary of what's behind the link. This is both to make it easier for readers to decide whether they want to take the time to follow the link, and to have some information left in case the link dies.

Comment: @Gilles, I am on it. Thnx for the suggestion.